# Vue 2 Images not rendering in some browsers

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Vue 2.4.2. I am rendering with v-for as following thanks to an axios returned array:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem; margin-left:1rem;" v-for="ad in ads" v-cloak>
      <img v-if="ad.image1" class="card-img-top" :src="'/public/ads/' + ad.image1" alt="Image">
      <img v-else class="card-img-top" src="/public/logo.png" alt="No Image">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">@{{ ad.title }}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
            @{{ ad.description }}<br><hr>
            <strong>$@{{ ad.cost }}</strong>
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use `:src`, `v-attr:src` and `v-bind:src`.

The information is being displayed successfully but the only that is not working is:

```
<img v-if="ad.image1" class="card-img-top" :src="'/public/ads/' + ad.image1" alt="Image">
```

This works great too:

```
<img v-else class="card-img-top" src="/public/logo.png" alt="No Image">
```

When I see the information loaded in the Developers Tools in Firefox I get the "No image" loaded great but there is a message when I hover the URL: "**Cannot load the**":

> **Edit 1:**
>   [image: Error]

The weird thing is that if in Developer Tools I copy the URL from src attribute and paste it in the browser I can see the image correctly.

> **Edit 2:** This is not the only weird thing, it also works on Microsoft Edge, and Google Chrome mobile, but not on Firefox or Google Chrome.

This is the generated element by Vue 2 according to Developer Tools:

```
<img src="/public/ads/hcpOW7aPhJFXWR8MP0poRfYYvmcRKjq2M6irUsD7.jpeg" alt="Imagen" class="card-img-top vjnhddxuzwlropukknbb">
```

And this is the generated element which is being displayed:

```
<img src="/public/logo.png" alt="No Imagen" class="card-img-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i test this example, but it works.

```js
data(){
 return {
  isShowImage : true,
  imgArr : ['banner.jpg', 'logo.png', 'about.jpg']
 }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="img of imgArr">
 <img v-if="isShowImage" src="/data/images/banner.jpg"  style="width:100px;height:30px;"/>
 <img v-else src="/data/images/logo.png" style="width:100px;height:30px;" />
</div>
<button @click="isShowImage = !isShowImage" type="button" name="button">show</button>
```

Are you sure your image path is right ?

Comment: I need to verify that is an image there, if not I use `v-else` to show another image. But I will read about `v-show` and how to implement it

Comment: @Maramal sorry, I wrong at last answer. I test it that works.  Can you use Firefox Dev Network tool to check the image path ? That's real not found the image if browser tell you "No image",

Comment: I've added an image of what Dev Tools look like, I copied and pasted exactly the same full qualified URL given by the browser and I am redirected to the image. and the weird thing is it works on Microsoft Edge and on my mobile, not on Firefox or Chrome